# Magento 1.9.0.1 SUPEE 8788 applied, query string with multiple parameter does not work

Tags: supee-8788v2

SUPEE 8788 v2 has been applied to our Magento CE 1.9.0.1 site. I just noticed that any url request with two and more query string parameters (http://www.domain.com/?p=1&sort=ASC) will result an error page (The webpage resulted in too many redirects). One parameter query string works fine.

I have reverted SUPEE 8788 v2 patch and the problem was gone. Is there anyone suffer this kind of problem? Anyone has clue on this? Thank you.

Comment: I like that this was marked as duplicate and forward to the main problems question then no one answered it.  We have duplicated this, as well.

Comment: The problem was caused by the code "return $this->escapeUrl($url);" under app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php. I replaced it by "return $url;" It may not be the best solution, but at least it works for my site.